# Restriction of "$\pi_{1}$" to topological groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, topological-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be two topological groups. Assume that $\phi:\pi_{1}(G) \to \pi_{1}(H)$ is  a group homomorphism. Is there a continuous function $f:G\to H$ such that $f_{*}=\phi$?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No. Take $G=SO(5)$ and $H=SO(3)$, both of which have fundamental group $\mathbb{Z}/2$. I claim that there is no continuous map $f: G\to H$ which induces the identity homomorphism.

If there were, then $f$ would induce  a nontrivial homomorphism $f_\ast: H_1(G;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H_1(H;\mathbb{Z}/2)$, and a graded ring homomorphism $f^\ast: H^\ast(H;\mathbb{Z}/2)\to H^\ast(G;\mathbb{Z}/2)$ which is nontrivial on $H^1$. To see that no such ring homomorphism exists, recall (see Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, section 3.D) that $$H^\ast(H;\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2[\alpha_1]/(\alpha_1^4)$$ and $$H^\ast(G;\mathbb{Z}/2)\cong \mathbb{Z}/2[\beta_1]/(\beta_1^8)\otimes\mathbb{Z}/2[\beta_3]/(\beta_3^2),$$ where each $\alpha_i,\beta_i$ is in degree $i$.

Comment: thank you very much for your interesting answer. what about for further assumption "G and H are path connected abelian topological group"?

Comment: For path connected abelian *Lie* groups the answer is yes (because they are all $K(\pi,1)$s). I don't know enough about general topological groups to answer your further question. In fact, I can't think of an example of a path connected abelian topological group which isn't a $K(\pi,1)$.

Comment: Topological abelian groups are products of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces so the answer is yes.

Comment: @nsrt A group homomorphism between product group is not necessarily a product of group homomorphism. Is not this statement an obstruction for your argument?

Comment: If G and H are topological abelian groups, then they are products of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces. So G has a "projection to the $\pi_1$ factor" and H has the "inclusion of the $\pi_1$ factor" i.e. the map you are asking for exists as a composition 
$G\to K(\pi_1G,1)\stackrel{K(\phi,1)}{\to} K(\pi_1H,1)\to H$.

Answer (score 1):

Not always. Take $G=H=\mathrm{PGL}(n,\mathbb{R})$, with $n\geq 7$. Every nontrivial continuous homomorphism $G\rightarrow G$ is a Lie automorphism; the group of such automorphisms is generated by inner automorphisms and $A\mapsto {}^tA^{-1} $, so it acts  on $\pi _1(G)$ through {$\pm 1$}. On the other hand $\pi _1(G)=\mathbb{Z}/n$ has  automorphisms $\neq \pm 1$.

**Edit**: Sorry, I misread the question - this answers a different question.

Comment: $f$ was assumed to be continuous, not a homomorphism.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I misread the question.